# Are there position markers in Open Office?

Tags: openoffice-writer

I'm editing a very large document in Open Office Writer and I basically have to jump between three different positions in the file.

When using Vim for plain text editing, I can set up *marks* and jump to them easily. Is there a similar functionality in Open Office? If so, how can I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to achieve this (I'm using Open Office 3.2).

- Define three "text markers" (I'm
  using German UI, so the phrases may
  differ).
- In the menu choose insert -> text
  marker (between caption/label and
  cross reference).
- Give those markers names as you need
  it.

To quickly jump to these markers:

- In the bottom right corner of your writer window (below the vertical scrollbar), there are three buttons: arrows up, a circle and arrows down.
- Click the circle button
- A popup appears. Select the icon for the text markers. The window closes.
- Now each time you click one of the arrow buttons the cursor will jump to the next/previous marker.

Comment: Excellent, do you know if there is any key combination for the jumps?

Comment: There is none by default, but you can define your own shortcuts. Menu Extras, then cusomize.